# what is default password for Role-Based Access Control (RABC) JBOSS EAP 6.3?

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, rbac

I am using `JBOSS EAP 6.3`, working with `domain mode`, I have installed and create user `admin` with passowrd `xxx`. I am able to login management console
Now I want to enable `Role-Based Access Control (RABC)` in `JBOSS`. I have modified `domain.xml` to enable `RABC`

```
<management>
        <access-control provider="rbac">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
</management>
```

Now the problem is I am trying to open management console using same **user** and **passoword** but it shows below error

[image]

what should be default credential for `RBAC` profile or I need to add user again after enabling `RBAC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bypass this error, you have to define a role-mapping from the groups or users defined in the realm to the desired roles.
For example, to grant SuperUser access to the user `admin` you have already created, use the following JBoss CLI command:

```
/core-service=management/access=authorization/role-mapping=SuperUser/include=user-admin:add(type=USER,name=admin)
```

You will see the following result in the domain.xml:

```
<access-control provider="rbac">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="admin"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
```